# Python 2.7 error in import

Tags: python, import, importerror

I know a lot of questions have been posted about the intra-package importing. I want to know whether the below is the way for Python 2.7 too.

```
Source/
anomalyCheck/
    __init__.py
    DLthput.py
    ULPowerStats.py
    ULThput.py
config/
    __init__.py
    configure.py
parserTools/
    __init__.py
    logParser.py
utilities/
    __init__.py
    plotLogResults.py
__init__.py
lteDebugger.py
```

---- lteDebugger.py----

```
import parserTools.logParser
import anomalyCheck.DLthput
import utilities.plotLogResults
import configuration.TDDFDDconfiguration
import anomalyCheck.ULthput
### Work done after here ####
```

------DLThput.py------

```
from ..utilities.plotLogResults import *
from ..parserTools.logParser import *
### Work done after here ####
```

------ULThput.py-------

```
from ..parserTools.logParser import *
from ..utilities.plotLogResults import *
```

Error :

Upon running the lteDebugger.py file, the error is

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package

File "C:\Users\manojtut\Desktop\Project_LTE_SVN\Source\lteDebugger.py", line 2, in 
  import anomalyChecker.DLthput
File "C:\Users\manojtut\Desktop\Project_LTE_SVN\Source\anomalyChecker\DLthput.py", line 1, in
```

I've read almost all available docs and Guido's guide for intra-package importing. Also, I guess I've everything exactly in the right place. Am I missing something here? Please point out. Thanks a lot in advance. :) :)

Edit 1: The Problem mentioned is solved by Amber's answer. So, lteDebugger.py is working fine by importing all other modules. Now, another problem is that, I am unable to solve is that... when I want to compile/interpret(whatever u want to call) the DLThput.py/ULthput.py , it is showing the same error as above ... ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package. Do I have any solution other adding paths to sys hacks? I really don't want to do that unless it's the only thing to do.
So, how can I dodge this?

Comment: in "from ..utilities.plotLogResults import *" why u r going back by putting ".." ??? i think u can still import with "from utilities.plotLogResults import *"

Comment: Nope, I don't think I can. Will check though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running `lteDebugger.py`, which means that any "packages" must be at least one level lower in the directory tree - they need to be contained inside a folder for Python to recognize them as packages rather than modules (and thus for relative imports to work).

`anomalyCheck` is recognized as a package, but its parent directory is not (because that's where `lteDebugger.py` is), and thus you aren't allowed to use relative imports to go up to that parent directory.

One way you could fix this is by moving everything except `lteDebugger.py` into a subdirectory, e.g.:

```
Source/
    debugger/
        anomalyCheck/
            __init__.py
            DLthput.py
            ULPowerStats.py
            ULThput.py
        config/
            __init__.py
            configure.py
        parserTools/
            __init__.py
            logParser.py
        utilities/
            __init__.py
            plotLogResults.py
        __init__.py
    lteDebugger.py
```

and then `lteDebugger.py` would do things like `import debugger.anomalyCheck.DLthput.py`.

Comment: Thanks for the early answer. So, you're telling to add the path of the directory in which the lteDebugger.py is in, to the sys. Right? Lemme try it.

Comment: That's one option, but if you do that, you wouldn't want to use relative paths - you'd want to use absolute paths. If you want to keep using relative paths, you'd want to use the method I edited into my answer.

Comment: lteDebugger.py is working fine by importing all other modules. Now, another problem is that, I am unable to solve is that... when I want to compile/interpret(whatever u want to call) the DLThput.py/ULthput.py , it is showing the same error as above ... 
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package

So, how can I dodge this?

Comment: The contents of packages aren't supposed to be run directly. If you want to interpret them, you'd usually just import them. You'd run Python from the top level directory (the same place you'd run `lteDebugger.py` from) and then do something like `>>> import debugger.anomalyCheck.DLThput`.

Comment: Also, just unaccepted ur answer so that my second problem will get solved. Will accept ur answer after a while.

Comment: Given what you're trying to do, I'd really suggest not using relative imports at all, but instead just using absolute imports. That way, you only have to add one directory to the pythonpath and everything within that will work.